# CMake build error - missing vtable for virtual method error

Tags: c++, cmake

Our Xcode C++ project is being converted to a CMake script. When building the CMake script, a missing vtable error keeps happening, if I use a class with virtual functions in my dummy main. If I only use a class without virtual functions in my main, everything builds fine.

The project builds fine for Xcode. What am I missing with my CMake script?

The CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
add_compile_options(-std=c++17)
SET (PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/source")

include_directories(
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/"
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main/"
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/hopscotch-map/"
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/rapidjson/"
)

add_executable(TestProject "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main/dummy-main.cpp")
install(TARGETS TestProject DESTINATION bin)
```

Main file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Player.hpp"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    auto player = Player{"John"};
    return 0;
}
```

The logs:

```
jess$ gmake -j 8 VERBOSE=1
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.13.3/bin/cmake -S/Users/jess/TestProject -B/Users/jess/TestProject --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.13.3/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/jess/TestProject/CMakeFiles /Users/jess/TestProject/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
gmake -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/Users/jess/TestProject'
gmake -f CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/depend
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/Users/jess/TestProject'
cd /Users/jess/TestProject && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.13.3/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/jess/TestProject /Users/jess/TestProject /Users/jess/TestProject /Users/jess/TestProject /Users/jess/TestProject/CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Dependee "source/BaseEntity.hpp" is newer than depends file "/Users/jess/TestProject/CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/depend.internal".
Clearing dependencies in "/Users/jess/TestProject/CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/depend.make".
Scanning dependencies of target TestProject
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/jess/TestProject'
gmake -f CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/build
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/Users/jess/TestProject'
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/source/main/dummy-main.cpp.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++   -I/Users/jess/TestProject -I/Users/jess/TestProject/source -I/Users/jess/TestProject/source/lib/hopscotch-map -I/Users/jess/TestProject/source/lib/rapidjson -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk   -std=c++17 -fPIC -fexceptions -g -O3 -o CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/source/main/dummy-main.cpp.o -c /Users/jess/TestProject/source/main/dummy-main.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable TestProject
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.13.3/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/source/main/dummy-main.cpp.o  -o TestProject
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Player::Player(std::__1::basic_string_view<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in dummy-main.cpp.o
  "vtable for BaseEntity", referenced from:
      Player::~Player() in dummy-main.cpp.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for Player", referenced from:
      Player::~Player() in dummy-main.cpp.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/build.make:84: TestProject] Error 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/jess/TestProject'
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/Users/jess/TestProject'
gmake: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Providing further details on `Player` is highly recommended. [mcve] is suggested.

Comment: You didn't add player.cpp as a dependency of the TestProject target executable.

Comment: @RichardHodges Doesn't include_directories add all the classes (in the selected folders) to all targets?

Comment: Yes, you were right @RichardHodges. Answer the question and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: @DanielRyan done, plus some other comments which I hope you'll find of use some day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is buried in the linker output:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Player::Player(std::__1::basic_string_view<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >)", referenced from:
  _main in dummy-main.cpp.o
  "vtable for BaseEntity", referenced from:
  Player::~Player() in dummy-main.cpp.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for Player", referenced from:
  Player::~Player() in dummy-main.cpp.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
```

Which immediately alerts me that you forgot to link the compilation unit containing the definitions of these functions.

Assuming that `Player` is defined in `player.hpp` and `player.cpp` and that they are in the subdirectory `src` then my suggestion would be to update the `add_executable` call to:

`add_executable(TestProject "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main/dummy-main.cpp" src/player.hpp src/player.cpp)`

Note that the "current source or binary directory" is assumed here and there is no need to spell it out.

Also note that I have included the header file as part of the target. There are a number of advantages to this:

- when generating project files for visual studio, xcode etc, these file will appear in the project tree.
- When using the latest `INSTALL` commands, these files can be given properties to ensure that they are treated properly (e.g. public or private header files for library targets)